# How to display the set object values in a jsp file instead of in a servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Good evening! I'm having trouble trying to convert this blocks of codes so it will display in a jsp instead of in a servlet. I do not know how to retrieve the items in my cartBean. 
Here is my cartController

```
<%
   session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1800);
String action = request.getParameter("action");
if(action.equals("Add"))  
try{               
  String upc = request.getParameter("upc");
  String name = request.getParameter("name");
  int quantity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity"));
  double price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price"));

   synchronized(session)  // lock session protect this from multiple threads
  {
   ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)session.getAttribute("Cart");
   if(cart == null)  // new sesssion, just create a cart
   {
    cart = new ShoppingCart();
    session.setAttribute("Cart", cart);
   }
   cart.add(item); 
   cart.display(out);
  } 
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   out.println(ex.toString()); 
  }
 }
else
 if(action.equals("Empty"))
 {
   synchronized(session)  
   {
    ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)session.getAttribute("Cart");
    if(cart == null) 
    {
     cart = new ShoppingCart();
     session.setAttribute("Cart", cart);
    }
    cart.empty(); 
    cart.display(out);
   }   
 }
%>
```

And here is my cartBean:

```
public class ShoppingCart {

ArrayList<Item> itemlist = new ArrayList<Item>();

public ShoppingCart()
{

}
 public void empty()
 {
   itemlist.clear();
 }
public void add(Item anitem)
{

 for(int i = 0; i < itemlist.size(); i++)
 {
 Item item = itemlist.get(i);
  if(anitem.upc.equals(item.upc))
  {
   item.quantity += anitem.quantity;
   return;
  }
 }
 itemlist.add(anitem);
}
```

Here is how my reference displayed the output in his servlet

```
 public void display(JspWriter out)
 {
 try{
  java.text.DecimalFormat currency = new java.text.DecimalFormat("$ #,###,##0.00");
  out.println("<h3>Cart contents</h3>");
  out.println("<table border=1>");
  out.println("<tr><th>UPC</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Total</th></tr>");

  double total = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < itemlist.size(); i++)
  {
   Item item = (Item)itemlist.get(i);
   out.println("<tr><td>"+item.upc+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+item.name+"</td>"+
              "<td align=right>"+ currency.format(item.price)+"</td>"+
              "<td align=right>"+ item.quantity+"</td>"+
              "<td align=right>"+ currency.format(item.price*item.quantity)+"</td></tr>");
   total += item.price*item.quantity;
  }
   out.println("<tr><td colspan = 4>Total purchase</td>");
   out.println("<td align=right>"+currency.format(total)+"</td></tr>");
   out.println("<tr><td colspan = 4>Sales tax @6%</td>"+
              "<td align=right>"+ currency.format(total*.06)+"</td></tr>");
   out.println("<tr><td colspan = 4>Amount due</td>"+
              "<td align=right>"+ currency.format(total*1.06)+"</td></tr>");
   out.println("</table>");

 }
 catch(IOException ex)
 {
  System.err.println(ex.toString());  // just send the exception to the error log
 }
```

}

If it might be necessary, here is the item bean

```
public class Item {

String upc = "";
String name = "";
int quantity = 0;
double price = 0;

public Item()
{

}

public Item(String upc, String name, int quantity, double price)
{
 this.upc = upc;
 this.name = name;
 this.quantity= quantity;
 this.price = price;
}
```

}

I tried to get the session attribute  but I do not know how to retrieve the products I added inside the cart. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it already. If anyone was wondering how, here's how:

```
public ArrayList<productBean> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
}

public void setItemList(ArrayList<productBean> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
}
```

I added this in my Item bean